# How can i pass the body parameters in Requests.PUT in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, put

I am working with a API to create a survey. The api url doesn't mention any 'data' parameter. The doc have body parameter but i am not sure if i should send a string or a json.

```
data = {
    'Id' : '60269c21-b4f8-4f58-b070-262179269d64',
    'Json' : '{ pages :[{ name : page1 , elements :[{ type : text , name : question1 }]}]}'
}
dddd = requests.put(f'https://api.surveyjs.io/private/Surveys/changeJson?accessKey={access_key}', data = data)

## dddd.status_code is 200 for this code.
```

but there is not change in the survey at all.
Can someone help me with this? [image]

Comment: Are you talking about the `requests` Python library? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, i have made changes in my question now

Comment: Try replacing `data` parameter name by `json`.

Comment: @MetallimaX i tried that as well gives same result